# Azure Functions Blob deployment

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I am going off the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-output?tabs=python

Here is the code I currently have:

**function.json**

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "queueName": "myqueue-items",
      "connection": "nameofstorageaccount_STORAGE",
      "name": "queuemsg",
      "type": "queueTrigger",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "name": "inputblob",
      "type": "blob",
      "dataType": "binary",
      "path": "samples-workitems/{queueTrigger}",
      "connection": "nameofstorageaccount_STORAGE",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "name": "outputblob",
      "type": "blob",
      "dataType": "binary",
      "path": "samples-workitems/{queueTrigger}-Copy",
      "connection": "nameofstorageaccount_STORAGE",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false,
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py"
}
```

***init.py***

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func


def main(queuemsg: func.QueueMessage, inputblob: bytes, outputblob: func.Out[bytes]):
    logging.info(f'Python Queue trigger function processed {len(inputblob)} bytes')
    outputblob.set(inputblob)
```

If I am understanding correctly, this function should get triggered when a blob is added to a container, and for it to save a copy of that blob inside the same container.

The functions runs, however nothing happens when a blob is uploaded to a container? I would like to trigger some code with a blob being uploaded, this is the only full example I have found with Python and Blob Trigger.

Appreciate any help,
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If you read the [`document`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-output?tabs=python#example), it states that the function is triggered when a message is sent to the queue:

> The following example shows blob input and output bindings in a
> function.json file and Python code that uses the bindings. The
> function makes a copy of a blob. **The function is triggered by a
> queue message that contains the name of the blob to copy**. The new
> blob is named {originalblobname}-Copy.

If you want to execute a function when a blob is created, please see `Blob Trigger` example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=python.

Comment: Thank You! I don't know how I missed this.....  My follow up question if you would not mind: If this is the case, do I need to reconfigure my **local.json** file in the way that it is above? and include the **direction:in** and **direction:out**? in order for the function to get triggered by a blob, and save the same blob back to storage after some code has modified it? or will the configuration in the link you provided be enough for this type of operation.

Comment: I'm not sure if you want to do that for saving a copy in the same container. You will be in an infinite loop then I believe because the moment you create a copy of the blob in the same container, the function will be triggered again and it will make a copy of the copy of the blob and the process will continue.

Comment: That makes sense - so the way forward would be to create a second container, and have the modified blob saving over there. I actually wanted to redirect the output blobs to either SQL or OneDrive or a hosting service that integrates well with Tableau. Would having a blob trigger and using an external Python SDK to redirect the modified blob to  OneDrive be an approach you'd recommend?

Comment: For OneDrive, I would actually recommend using Logic Apps instead of Azure Functions. I believe there are already a connector available for OneDrive which will automatically upload the file there.

Comment: But would it be possible to run my python script to change the file beforehand ? I get the file in an attachment via email, I want to transform it, then only after re-save to OneDrive

Comment: I think we are getting carried away in the discussions :). Please post a new question with all the details. I hope someone with experience will be able to provide a better answer.

Comment: well, my original thought would be to use logic apps to redirect the blob from blob storage to one drive, you've just took out the middle step, appreciate the help! :)